# Is there a way to compare two members' rankings?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a Discord bot. I am coding warn command but I need a code to compare two members' (role) rankings. Example: A person is higher than B person. If B person tries to warn A person, bot says 'You can not warn this person.'. If A person tries to warn B person, bot warns B person.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Get each member's highest role and compare their calculated positions**

By getting a [GuidMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)'s [Highest Role](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=highestRole) and getting that [Role](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role)'s [Calculated Position](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=calculatedPosition), we can use this value to compare with other member's highest role's calculated positions to see who's higher up according to the server's role manager.

```js
// I'll assume you already have the data for both members (memberA and memberB)
let rankingA = memberA.highestRole.calculatedPosition;
let rankingB = memberB.highestRole.calculatedPosition;

if (rankingA > rankingB) {
  // apply warning
} else {
  // reject warning
}
```

Notes:

- `.highestRole` will return the role object itself.
- `.calculatedPosition` will return an integer, higher value means higher ranking.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me and my bot. But I have a question. If the A person is the guild's owner, can this code work?

Comment: This code doesn't check for that, since it only looks at roles. Take a look at the docs for [`Guild.ownerID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=ownerID) to help you out with this extra task

Answer (score 0):

So you'd initially need to setup a counting system to count their permissions, maybe it could be role based. You could store this in a simple SQL DB, or an array etc. Relatively simple. Say if I had `x` role, I'd have `x` points. This could be done with `if (user.role === 'blah') points = x` or something simple like that.

If you didn't want to do the counting system, look into *Role#calculatedPosition* - that'll return the height in the list of roles on your Discord server. For example;

`const roleX = message.role.calculatedPosition()`

`const otherRole = message.role.calculatedPosition()`

You'd need to look for how to go about calling the role and its ID.

Once that's done, do something like

```js
if (points.a > points.b) {

// do something here like  allow/reject it
message.channel.send('warn stuff')
} else {
  //reject it here, for example
  message.channel.send('no')
  return
}
```

Let me know how ya got on.