# See permission value of a user in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm fairly new to Discord.js and I was wondering how to get the value permissions for a user. I want to do this because I want to make sure someone with a low rank doesn't kick someone with a higher rank. I've tried to search it up online but I get linked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901755/is-there-a-way-to-compare-two-members-rankings) post, which doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can get their permissions by `<GuildMember>.permissions`.

If you want to check if they have a certain permission you would do

`<GuildMember>.permissions.has(Permission_Resolvable)`

Example:

```js
const member = msg.mentions.members.first();
const permissions = member.permissions;
const isMod = permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS");
if(!isMod) return msg.channel.send("You are not a mod");
```

Permission.has here:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=has

Full flags here:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS

The post you linked is outdated in v12, but here's the new code:

```js
// I'll assume you already have the data for both members (memberA and memberB)
const rankingA = memberA.roles.highest.position;
const rankingB = memberB.roles.highest.position;

if(rankingA > rankingB) {

} else if (rankingA < rankingB) {

} else {

}
```

Or

```js
// I'll assume you already have the data for both members (memberA and memberB)
const highestA = memberA.roles.highest;
const highestB = memberB.roles.highest;

//check if memberA is higher
const isHigher = highestA.comparePositionTo(highestB);

if(isHigher > 0) {
  //memberA is higher
} else if(isHigher < 0) {
  //memberB is higher
} else {
  //same
}
```